# How to retrieve the QPainter object in QML Canvas object

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QML Canvas, on which I'm drawing in C++ by overriding the `paint(QPainter *painter)` method and using a bunch of statements that use that `painter` object.

Stuff like...

```
void myGraphDisplay::paint (QPainter* painter) {

    QPainterPath path;
    path.MoveTo(0, 0);
    path.LineTo(100, 100);
    painter->strokePath(path, painter->pen());
```

etc.

Now some time later, another function wants to draw on the canvas, but the `painter` object is no longer available. I have tried saving it as a private member of the myGraphDisplay class but my application crashes if I try to access it again in the later function.

```
void myGraphDisplay::updateGraph () {
    QPainterPath path;
    path.MoveTo(100, 0);
    path.LineTo(0, 100);
    painter->strokePath(path, painter->pen()); // where do I get "painter" here?
```

I also tried

```
QPainter painter(this);
```

as shown on the [QT reference pages](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html) but that gives me an error...

> no matching function for call to QPainter::QPainter(myGraphDisplay*)

How do I get the current `QPainter` object? If it's any help, `updateGraph()` is a `Q_INVOKABLE` called from the same QML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules state that the process of painting a QQuickItem occurs in the paint method, not in another method. The generic solution is:

1. Save the painting information in some attribute of the class.
2. Invoke the paint method
3. Implement the logic in the paint method.

***.h**

```cpp
private:
    QPainterPath m_path;
```

***.cpp**

```
myGraphDisplay::myGraphDisplay(QQuickItem *parent): QQuickItem(parent){
    // default path
    m_path.MoveTo(0, 0);
    m_path.LineTo(100, 100);
}

void myGraphDisplay::updateGraph(){
    QPainterPath path;
    path.MoveTo(100, 0);
    path.LineTo(0, 100);
    m_path = path;
    update();
}

void myGraphDisplay::paint (QPainter* painter) {
    painter->strokePath(m_path, painter->pen());
}
```